# Easier way of making the "player" move across the array

Tags: c#

Right now I have the 1, or "player" moving across a small array using the right arrow using this... bad code. What is a simpler and more condensed way of taking the arrow key input and moving the "player" in the direction across the screen. Mine works currently, but only on index [2,x]. It doesn't allow any other movement on other index, obviously, nor does it allow for any movement in any other direction. The only way to do that with my current method would be to write hundreds of line of code for simple movement of a 1 across a bunch of 0's and then it doesn't even include everything else i want to do with this simple little console game/application.

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo rightOne;
    bool rightMoveEnd = true;

    do 
    {
      rightOne = Console.ReadKey();

      if(rightOne.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && board[2,0] == 0)
      {

        board[2,0] = 0;
        board[2,1] = 1;
        Console.Clear();

        for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
          for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            Console.Write(board[row,col] + " ");
          }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

      if(rightOne.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && board[2,1] == 1)
      {

        board[2,1] = 0;
        board[2,2] = 1;
        Console.Clear();

        for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
          for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            Console.Write(board[row,col] + " ");
          }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

      if(rightOne.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && board[2,2] == 1)
      {

        board[2,2] = 0;
        board[2,3] = 1;
        Console.Clear();

        for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
          for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            Console.Write(board[row,col] + " ");
          }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

      if(rightOne.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && board[2,3] == 1)
      {

        board[2,3] = 0;
        board[2,4] = 1;
        Console.Clear();

        for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
          for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            Console.Write(board[row,col] + " ");
          }
        Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
      }

      if(board[2,4] == 1)
      {
        rightMoveEnd = false;
      }
    }
    while(rightMoveEnd == true);
  }
```

Comment: Just keep track of the row/column of the player and check against the bounds of the array. There's no need to check every combination of where the player might be.